# stop VS2017 from editing IISExpress applicationhost.config file

Tags: iis-express, visual-studio-2017

When debugging a WebAPI project in VS2017 I set up my applicationhost.config so that IISExpress is open to external requests.  In my case, the url in the binding line looks like this:

```html
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:64895:*" />
```

The problem I'm having is every time I close VS2017, its creating a whole new site presumably since the binding in the project properties is http://localhost:64895.  So every time I open the project, I have to edit the applicationhost.config file which I didn't have to do in VS2015.

Is there a way to fix VS2017 so its not creating a new site every time?

Comment: I've got this same issue in VS2015. It might be the standard way the web projects works now though I cant figure out how to suppress this. I end up with a new ```<site name="myapp (###)" id="###">``` every time I open the project.

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28330670/1161132. Resolved my issues in VS2015. Remove all the extra  ```<site>``` nodes leaving only the Default "WebSite1" node and a single ```<site>``` node for your app. Add a binding for both ```*:64895:*``` and ```*:64895:localhost```